# What is the cleanest way to use a Promise in my AWS query function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I feel like my current implementation of this function is messy and am looking to make it cleaner. I've seen examples online and there's so many different ways to use Promises. I'm not sure which way would be the best for this scenario.

I've looked over the [AWS documentation examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-query-scan.html), but they're using an `if else` statement. It doesn't return the results I need sometimes, so that's why I've resorted to using a Promise. I've also looked at this guide that uses promises: [AWS documentation Promise example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html).

**My current function:**

```
async function queryTable(params) {
   return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ddb.query(params, (err, data) => {
         if (err) {
           console.log(err);
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(data.Items);
          }
       });
   });
 }
```

**My Attempt:**

```
async function queryTable(params) {
  const data = await ddb.query(params).promise();
  data.then(function (data) {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Is this a good way to go about it?

Comment: In your first function, `async` and `await` are redundant -- you're already returning a promise.

Comment: Your attempt, the second function... is there a problem with it? Is it not doing what you want it to? Can you explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: @TKoL I'm wondering whether my implementation is correct and clean. I also use `async` and `await` with a promise in my attempt - Is this also redundant?

Comment: The best way to tell if it's correct is to try it. Assuming `ddb.query(params).promise()` returns a promise that resolves with data, then... yes, I think you did make a mistake. `const data = await ...` should result in data NOT being a promise, but a data structure. So there's most likely not a `data.then()` function on that -- the data is the data. But you should set some breakpoints and find out.